# List Json Parse Error, Detect partial object JSON Format Error- Aspnet Webapi

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a class

```
class Sample
{
    public string str1;
    public string str2;
    public string str3;
    public string str4;
    public DateTime date1;
    public DateTime date2;
}
```

And I'm using `Aspnet Webapi Http Post` method and need to parse body,

Generally, if the body's JSON Format has big error, such as lack a bracket at the start:

```
[
"str1": "32226","str2":"ABC","str3" :"91492","str4":"AC","date1":"1997-04-23T18:25:43",
"date2":"1997-04-23T18:25:43"
},
{"str1": "3226","str2":"ABF","str3" :"492","str4":"AB","date1":"1997-04-23T18:25:43","date2":"1997-04-23T18:25:43"
}
]
```

When use `[FromBody]List<Sample> samples` to parse the body, you'll get `samples = null`, so you can use null to tell that the body's json format is error,

But when I try just make a property's DateTime JSON format error, such as date2 in the first object below:

```
[
{"str1": "32226","str2":"ABC","str3" :"91492","str4":"AC","date1":"1997-04-23T18:25:43",
"date2":"1997-04-2325:43" -> date2 error datetime string 
},
{"str1": "3226","str2":"ABF","str3" :"492","str4":"AB","date1":"1997-04-23T18:25:43","date2":"1997-04-23T18:25:43"
}
]
```

then use `[FromBody]List<Sample> samples` to parse, It can succesfully parse the Second `Sample` Object, and show that the List Count of `samples` equals 1,

but there isn't any exception or information I can tell that the first object's is JSON Parsed Failed, which if two objects are all parsed correct will make the `samples` Count to be 2.

I try to change the DateTime Type into DateTime?, however, it's the same only the second object is parsed, and first object is  omitted silently.

Is there any way to Detect this kind of error, that only some of the object's JSON format is error?

I can think a plain method is to count the char `{` present times , and compare to the List Count, if `{`'s Count < List Count, then there must be some object aren't parsed succesfully, but it seems not a good way.

Answer (score 1):

*`but there isn't any exception or information I can tell that the first object's is JSON Parsed Failed`*

Yes there  is a way  to  see if the JSON parsed with an error

in your `Application_Start()`
just do the following

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Error +=
            delegate(object sender, ErrorEventArgs args)
            {
                                   
                File.WriteAllText(@"c:\\temp\\jsonerrortest.txt", args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);                                    
                
            };   
    }
```

**Updated**

From your Comment:

*`Is there way to tell during the execution? I want to tell the parsed error in the post method and throw an exception inform the user that the input body is wrong.`*

Yes there is way fo doing this you have to intercept your messgae with  `DelegatingHandler`
Something like the following:

```
public  class MessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        
        string requestInfo = string.Empty;
        
      
          
            requestInfo = string.Format("{0}:{1}", request.Method, request.RequestUri);
            var requestMessage = await request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            IncommingMessageAsync( requestInfo, requestMessage);
        

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        
            byte[] responseMessage;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                if (response.Content != null)
                    responseMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                else
                    responseMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response.ReasonPhrase);

            }
            else
                responseMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response.ReasonPhrase);          
            OutgoingMessageAsync( requestInfo, responseMessage);        

        return response;
    }
    protected void IncommingMessageAsync(string requestInfo, byte[] message)
    {

       var obj =JObject.Parse(Convert.ToString(message)); 
    }    
    protected void OutgoingMessageAsync( string requestInfo, byte[] message)
    {
        
    }
}
```

note in your `IncomingMessageAsync` if there is

```
  var obj =JObject.Parse(Convert.ToString(message));
```

which will raise the exception in verbose mode in case of a parsing error

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.",
  "ExceptionType": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException",
  "StackTrace": "   à Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()\r\n   à Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()\r\n   à Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader)\r\n   à Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json)\r\n   à MessageHandler.IncommingMessageAsync(String requestInfo, Byte[] message) dans c:\\tests\\WebApplication2\\WebApplication2\\MessageHandler.cs:ligne 45\r\n   à MessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext() dans c:\\tests\\WebApplication2\\WebApplication2\\MessageHandler.cs:ligne 21\r\n--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---\r\n   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   à System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"
}
```

**Note**
for security reason **Never ever do this**

create a custom exception instead

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try it later. Is there way to tell during the execution logic code? I want to tell the parsed error in the post method so that I can return an exception HttpResponseMessage to inform the user  when the input body is wrong.